# Microsoft Project- Get all GUIDs (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, task, add-in, ms-project

How does one go about getting all of the Task GUIDs in MS-Project, from the current project? I'm very familiar with when you need to get data from the selected task, but I'm no longer in that friendly realm.

Answer (score 1):

You can get these with an ODATA query:

```
[PWA URL]/_api/ProjectData/Projects(guid'[PROJECT GUID]')/Tasks?$select=TaskId
```